MudBlazor custom carousel with pagination component
I need a carousel with pagination below it so I downloaded its source code and I inserted a pagination control at the end of the carousel component. Unfortunatelly it is not working because it doesn't load the ItemSource. Of course, I didn't just download the carousel code but its parent abstract classes and MudCarouselItem.
Could someone help me to solve this problem, please?
UPDATE
Now the problem with ItemSource is solved because I forgot to replace MudCarouselItem with my class.
Another problem has emerged: I cannot use @bind-Selected in the pagination component because I am using the SelectedChanged event callback, so I cannot mark the selected page number after a MoveTo call.

Can you add some code? It will help to solve your problem.
My guess is, you can set the Selected Value inside the SelectedChanged event.
private void SelectedChanged(int selected){
//stuff //
_selected = selected;
}
